# Navmenu bar disappears when I active Bootstrap css

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, conflict

After I active Bootstrap to my theme I am developing in Wordpress - my nevmenu disappeared. It is there when I scale the website down (max widt 980px) and is visible as a collapse menu. Maybe there is some .nav styling from Bootstrap that are conflicting with my theme.

Can you please help me finding out what it is?

Here is a link to the website: http://list.thorsteinnhelgason.is/index.php/2018/02/15/prufupostur/
Best B

Comment: If either answer below was helpful, I'd recommend upvoting them. Click the gray arrow above the number to the left of the answer.  (Note that it appears you haven't accepted / upvoted any of the answers that have been provided to your questions).

Answer (score 0):

Saw your site, you messed up the content within `navbar`, your `nav` is there but it's not displaying at a block level.

I would suggest you use this one instead, I'm using the same. [wp-bootstrap-navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker). The developer has explained a great deal of using it. Try it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion - I would definitely do that :)

Answer (score 0):

The navbar you are using is Bootstrap v4, but your stylesheet is using v2.3.2: http://list.thorsteinnhelgason.is/wp-content/themes/listin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

If you are unable to upgrade WordPress for some reason, you can add this style:

```css
.navbar-toggleable-md .collapse {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

And change your HTML to this:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">...
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Tim - It worked when I updated Wordpress - Thanks alot, you saved me a lot of time :)